# how to add a loop to Python script that scrapes a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a script that scrapes a website. However, I am looking for it to incrementally scrape the websites for a range. So imagine the range is set to 0-999. The code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.greekrank.com/uni/1/sororities/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

uni = soup.find_all('h1', class_='overviewhead')
for title in uni:
    print(title.text)

rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='desktop-view')
for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

It would go to https://www.greekrank.com/uni/1/sororities/ scrape that, then go to https://www.greekrank.com/uni/2/sororities/ scrape that, etc.

Comment: Well, just write a `for` loop? You’ve already written two of them so you should know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it all in a loop. Also note the URL assignment.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for x in range(0, 999):
    URL = f'https://www.greekrank.com/uni/{x}/sororities/'
    page = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    uni = soup.find_all('h1', class_='overviewhead')
    for title in uni:
        print(title.text)

    rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='desktop-view')
    for row in rows:
        print(row.text)
```

Comment: Also, take care to add some delay after each iteration so that you are not overloading the server with requests!

Comment: When I run this in IDLE it doesn't seem to show anything. Would you know where this would be getting caught? If the website doesn't exist (like say "12") would it bypass it and keep going or just stick around on that forever?

Comment: i tried the following but didn't work:

import requests
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for x in range(0, 10):
    try:
        URL = f'https://www.greekrank.com/uni/{x}/sororities/'
        page = requests.get(URL)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        uni = soup.find_all('h1', class_='overviewhead')
        for title in uni:
            print(title.text)

        rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='desktop-view')
        for row in rows:
            print(row.text)
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

Comment: You could add a check on the status code just after the request. If it's not what you expect (probably 200), then `continue`.